# Validation rule to limit possible parent records for service appointment

Tags: validation-rule, field-service-lightning

According to this: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_appointment_guidelines.htm&type=5

To limit objects that could be parents for Service appointment I should create validation rule that check first 3 characters.
Example for work orders: LEFT(ParentRecordId, 3) = '0WO'
But: first of all I cant even choose ParentRecord(Id) from the list of fields when creating validation rule. Secondly after typing it manually i recieve syntax error.

Is there any other way to limit parent records (maybe also in user interface -> so user wont have an option to choose for example Account)?
Is there possibility to fix above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an error in the documentation that will be corrected. The ParentRecordId field isn't available in validation rules. However a couple alternative options exist to do the same kind of validation you want:

- Perform the validation in an Apex trigger
- Create a new custom text field of length 18 and copy the ParentRecordId value to the field in a Before trigger. Then use that custom field in a normal validation rule.

Comment: Well I already did the validation in a trigger long time ago, but lets say that "mistake in documentation" is an answer :)